# Cancelable Promise loses cancel property when accessed in foreign class object

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm having troubles cancelling promise from the context that is different from the one the promise was created in. For instance this is how i create a cancelable promise:

```
import PCancelable from 'p-cancelable';

class Common {

 static runPromise(){

 const fetchPromise = new PCancelable((resolve, reject, onCancel) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     resolve({ ok: true, data: [1, 2, 3] });
   }, 10000);

   onCancel(() => {
     console.log('Promise is being canceled');
   });
 });

 console.log(fetchPromise) //PCancelable type
 //this works and will cancel the promise
 //fetchPromise.cancel();

 return fetchPromise;
 }
}
```

Then I'm trying to call this static method from a different class and do a cancel on it like this:

```
const promise = Common.runPromise().then().catch();
console.log(promise ) //Promise type - I expect it to be PCancelable
promise.cancel();  //outputs promise.cancel is not a function
```

when i run a check:

```
console.log(promise)
```

if returns instance of "Promise" class. instead of "PCancelable" as it would do if I log it in original(Common) class.

How do i cast an output of static function "runPromise" to a "PCancellable" so it works as i want to?

Comment: you aren't calling `runPromise`?

Comment: Did you try: 
const promise = Common.runPromise();
promise.cancel();  ?

Comment: @JoãoOtero yes, I'm sorry, just fixed in question. the question is still relevent

Comment: in the examples of p-cancelable they are calling .cancel() when the promise is being awaited... does it work if you `await promise` before trying to cancel it?

Comment: I tried it at - https://repl.it/@sunnykgupta/TryingpCancelable , 
Works as expected. Mind sharing code where you say this wouldn't work?

Comment: I have a fetch inside my original promise, so i'm trying to reproduce the problem in sandbox now

Comment: Sure, let me know once you encounter the same problem in sandbox and we can try to help you accordingly.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta It was returning a regular promise since i did console.log(Common.runPromise().then().catch()); once i changed to console.log(Common.runPromise()) everything worked as expected. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying the above code on - https://repl.it/@sunnykgupta/TryingpCancelable gives me the expected output.

You're modifying the promise object enroute between returning the `PCancelable` and calling `.cancel` on that.

Basically, using an object in a different class would not change its constructor unless done explicitly or implicitly in this case by the `then` you've used.